# Homebrew doesn't install new apps in El Capitan

Tags: macos, xcode, homebrew

just upgraded to beta El Capitan for developers.

```
Deniss-MBP:src me$ brew install hg
Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
==> Downloading https://mercurial.selenic.com/release/mercurial-3.4.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/mercurial-3.4.2.tar.gz
==> make PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/3.4.2 install-bin
#include <stdio.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build] Error 1

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.
We do not provide support for this pre-release version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakage.
```

**Any ideas how to make it work?**

Note:
When I do `brew doctor` it says

```
Warning: Your Xcode (6.3.2) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 7.0.
Xcode can be updated from
  https://developer.apple.com/downloads
```

But I do have xcode-beta 7 installed on my computer. Not sure this is linked. Just in case

Comment: `brew update` fixed `Warning: You are using OS X 10.11.` for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I recommend you go over this:
https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3994os/rootless_feature_is_in_os_x_1011_and_it_disallows/

The rootless security changed a lot of things in El Capitan, other than that where does your `xcode-select` point to?
You can use 
`xcode-select -h` to see the usage, it's very simple.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction I type 
`xcode-select -p` which pointed to the old version of Xcode (not the beta). So I switched the path to the Xcode-beta.app like so: 
`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`
(Had to sudo or it doesn't work)

Comment: Glad to help. another tip: `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/` should work too.

Answer (score 14):

Check out [El Capitan & Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md):

#### If `/usr/local` exists already:

```
sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

#### If `/usr/local` does not exist:

- Reboot into Recovery mode (Hold Cmd+R on boot) & access the Terminal.
- In that terminal run: `csrutil disable`
- Reboot back into OS X
- Open your Terminal application and execute:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /usr/local && sudo chflags norestricted /usr/local && sudo chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
  ```
- Reboot back into Recovery Mode & access the Terminal again.
- In that terminal execute: `csrutil enable`
- Reboot back into OS X & you'll be able to write to `/usr/local` & install Homebrew.

Comment: The doc you reference is now gone.

Answer (score 3):

Making a `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` will break any agents that may be stored under `/usr/local` subfolders, that must be owned by `root:wheel`.

<sup>Note: in El Capitan, `root:wheel` is the default `user:group` that is set for `/usr/local` and its subfolders.</sup>

In addition, people might have 3rd party kernel extensions that must be also have `root:wheel` permissions (e.g. antivirus software), otherwise OS X will prevent them to be loaded.

So setting `/usr/local` to `$(whoami)` is definitely the worst idea to do.