# Trouble installing fish shell on OS X non-admin user group

Tags: macos, bash, shell, iterm2, fish

I am struggling to install the fish shell on OS X El Capitan.

My user structure is setup so I have an administrator account and a standard account. The standard account is the one that I use and simply have the admin account for security reasons. However, I am unable to install fish on my standard account. It is installed perfectly on my admin account, but when I change the shell from bash to fish, I get the following error in iTerm2:

> A session ended very soon after starting. Check that the command in profile "my_admin_username" is correct.

In the shell, I am also receiving the following error:

```
login: /usr/local/bin/fish: Permission denied
```

Now, the above would make sense, as I am only able to use fish when `su`ing, but I have been unsuccessful thus far in setting fish up correctly to work across all of my accounts.

This is a clean, recent install so I am not sure what is causing this error. I can revert to bash easily, but I really want to be able to use fish.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the permissions of /usr/local/bin/fish? The fish maintainer is active on stackoverflow, so you might want to ask there if you don't get any good answers here.

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x   1 root      wheel  743892 Jul 12 03:34 fish

Answer (score 1):

El Capitan introduced a feature called [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) that restricts *even the root user* from performing certain actions on some system directories, `/usr/local` included.

[this](https://superuser.com/questions/940874) might be relevant.

Comment: Problem is solved http://superuser.com/questions/984613/is-administrator-account-necessary-in-order-to-use-shells-such-as-zsh-and-fish