# Is administrator account necessary in order to use shells such as zsh and fish?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, zsh, fish

I have a weird situation. I’m using Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) and iTerm2.

Zsh is listed by default in `/etc/shells` as `/bin/zsh`, and this allows me to use Zsh without any issues on my **standard** account.

However, when I `brew install` Zsh and then use `chsh` or `System Preferences -> User Groups -> etc`, I get a `login: /usr/local/bin/zsh: Permission denied` error. This is *after* adding `/usr/local/bin/zsh` to `/etc/shells`.

I have run into the same problem with [Fish](http://fishshell.com), which is actually the shell I would prefer to be using. Now, I can use the shell without any issues when I `su` to an account with administrator access, but I can’t use these shells on my standard account.

As I mentioned earlier, the paths are added to `/etc/shells` and I have set the permissions to 755, but I still am having no luck.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or must I simply use an admin account in order to take advantage of these shells?

This is really disappointing, because I appreciate the heightened security of working in a standard account, but it sucks not being able to get the best shells outside of my admin account.

---

I want to emphasize that I am able to get Zsh working on my standard account *only* when using the path that is set by default, which is `/bin/zsh` in `/etc/shells`. This makes me question if there is some issue with the path being in `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

However, this is the default, so I am wondering if there are others who are using a standard account with fish or a *brewed* zsh with success.

I have found little to no documentation on this.

Comment: I am looking to run fish/zsh as my default shell

Comment: Also, from what I understand, the syntax that you suggested is no longer valid in OS X. It is the native Linux command. The OS X command is now `chsh -s $SHELL`

Comment: I just included `$SHELL` as a stand-in for a generic shell. When I use the command in El Capitan, it gives me a usage error

Comment: I stand corrected. It appears to work just fine (when changing to bash). However, when I do the following: `chsh -s $(which fish)` or `chsh -s $(which zsh)` I get this: `usage: chpass [-l location] [-u authname] [-s shell] [user]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Homebrew set up for multiple users?  If not, take a look at this simple explanation: http://blog.strug.de/2012/06/my-homebrew-multi-user-setup/.

If it is, then make sure `brew doctor` shows good for each user you intend to give access to `brew`.

---

If you don't want it set up for multiple users, and you only want `zsh` and `fish` to work for multiple users, then you'll have to do some manual permissions fiddling.

Homebrew doesn't install to `/usr/local`.  "Homebrew installs packages to their own directory and then symlinks their files into /usr/local."  So `755` perms on `/usr/local/bin/fish` are useless.  In fact, the simlinks should be set to `777`.

You'll need to follow the links and set `755` on the actual executables instead.  Also, be sure that all dirs leading to the simlinks are set to `+x` so that others can see the simlinks.

*The above quote is from Homebrew's website: brew.sh*

Comment: I went through the above regarding setting up Homebrew to work across multiple accounts, however, I had no success getting it to work on my standard account despite following the instructions verbatim

Comment: Steps 4 and 6 of the guide add write perms for all brew users.  Since you had Homebrew for a while before trying this, you may need to also add read and/or execute perms during those steps.  If that doesn't work, I recommend using the second part of my answer to manually set perms on the shells you want to share.  Once you're current problem is fixed, you can go back and decided how much you want to put into making Homebrew work for multiple users.

Comment: Perfect. Once I changed permissions to `+x` for `/Cellar` I was golden. `brew` is now working across both accounts as well as `fish`. Thanks Tyler